# Rendering two objects in OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Im trying to add two objects, which is created from one part, but since i need to color each part i have seperated them. I have tried to render one part which works, but i have afterwards tried to render both which renders nothing.

```
        glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_boxVAO);
        glBindVertexArrayOES(_boxVAO);

        int sizeOfFaces = myMesh_m.faces.size() * sizeof(ObjMeshFace);
        glGenBuffers(1, &_boxBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _boxBuffer);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfFaces, &(myMesh_m.faces[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)(sizeof(Vector3f) + sizeof(Vector2f)));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        sizeOfFaces = myMesh_p.faces.size() * sizeof(ObjMeshFace);
        glGenBuffers(1, &_boxBuffer_sec);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _boxBuffer_sec);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfFaces, &(myMesh_p.faces[0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(ObjMeshVertex), (void*)(sizeof(Vector3f) + sizeof(Vector2f)));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

        glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

Draw:

```
            glBindVertexArrayOES( _boxVAO);
            glUniform2fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, color);
            glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, GL_FALSE, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, pointerSize_m*3);
```

Shader.vsh

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main()
{
    vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(1, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

    float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition)));

    colorVarying = diffuseColor * nDotVP;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

Shader.fsh

```
//varying lowp vec4 colorVarying;
uniform lowp vec4 color;


void main()
{
//    gl_FragColor = colorVarying;
    gl_FragColor = color;

}
```

Why does this fail? Furthermore how do i color each object?

Comment: Where is your initialization of `_boxVAO_NEW`? If that is your real code then you're not programming it.

Comment: IF what changes between both objects is only the color, you dont even need to create a new VAO, just add an uniform into the shader and change the value of that uniform before each different draw.

Comment: @Tim, my mistake was corrected while struggling yesterday. I will update this.

Comment: @LuisOscar, can you give an code example? Thanks.

Comment: @JavaCake are you using ES 1 or ES 2? I have no idea about ES 1 so i cant help you there. if it is ES 2 then you change it by binding the new uniform before the second draw.

Comment: @LuisOscar, i am using ES 2 in this case..

Comment: Then yes and its pretty easy, check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes on the draw method. The color declaration should be outside the drawing method unless you have a variable that changes. (Like I have this inside the drawing loop because I would have "x" instead of 200)

```
GLfloat color[4];
color[0] = 200/255.0;
color[1] = 0.0/255.0;
color[2] = 0.0/255.0;
color[3] = 255.0/255.0;

GLfloat colorOther[4];
color[0] = 50/255.0;
color[1] = 0.0/255.0;
color[2] = 0.0/255.0;
color[3] = 255.0/255.0;

glUseProgram(_programBorder);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vaoBorder);
glUniform2fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_BORDER], 1, color);
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX_BORDER], 1, GL_FALSE, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

//Modify the model projection matrix to change the position of the object

glUniform2fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_BORDER], 1, colorOther);
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX_BORDER], 1, GL_FALSE, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

The fragment shader has to have the uniform like this:

```
uniform lowp vec4 color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

And dont forget to link this uniform properly on your program creation methods.

Comment: Can i ask what _programBorder and _vaoBorder is? Is _vaoBorder just my own VAO?

Comment: programBorder is my program (used in es 2) which contains my fragment and vertex shaders.

Comment: vaoBorder is the vertex array object, here you use yours, which should be set once and will contain your configuration for that specific type of draw call.

Comment: So is the programBorder necessary since i have not defined such variable. Furthermore `uniforms` is not working, missing library?

Comment: That is just a structure... Create a new xcode project using the opengl es 2 template, you can see all those elements there.

Comment: I have tried the template but neither `UNIFORM_COLOR_BORDER` or `UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX_BORDER` are used. In other words they are causing problems.

Comment: Because these are just pointers to the ones you set during your program creation. On the template scroll to loadshaders method, there they set the variable for that uniform. In my case I have many so I placed them in an array of enum.

Comment: Similar to `uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
    uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "normalMatrix");` so it confuses me how i should deal with those two variables.

Comment: Look at the header, like i said, they are just enums of GLint. You could just add something like GLint modelmatrix; on the header and modelmatrix = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix"); on the loadshader code.

Comment: So far my object is still black. Should i do anything with my `Shader.vsh`? Main code updated..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late to add to the mix, but I was just looking at the answer and it didn't work for me - I had a black square, however I changed

```
glUniform2fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_BORDER], 1, color);
```

to

```
glUniform4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_COLOR_BORDER], 1, color);
```

And it works now. Should this be 4, as there are 4 values in a colour or is my code messed up elsewhere that this works? :P